# Changing the date format if not correct in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a mobile app that scans a QR-CODE that has various information embedded within it. One of the bits of information is a date.

There has been changes with in the QR-CODE from the previous versions with the format of the date. The previous date format was mm/dd and the new version is yy-MM-dd.

I am able to get it to scan the new version of the labels or the old ones, but not both. I need to get it to recognize bot types. I am not sure if there is a way to use an if statement to recognize the old format and convert it to the new format.

Here is an example of the working code using the new labels.

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('Controllers', []);
var baseUrl = 'https://apps.laticrete.com/LSCWebApiService/lscapi/';

app.controller('BarcodeCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$http', 'alertsManager', '$timeout', 'localStorageService', '$cordovaBarcodeScanner', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$filter',
    function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $http, alertsManager, $timeout, localStorageService, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, $cordovaGeolocation, $filter) {
        var SessionId = localStorageService.get('SessionId');

        // Get GeoLocation
        $cordovaGeolocation
            .getCurrentPosition()
            .then(function(position) {
                $scope.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        $scope.long = position.coords.longitude;
            });

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    $scope.scanMaterial = function() {


        $cordovaBarcodeScanner
            .scan()
            .then(function(result) {

                var codeArray = result.text.split(',');
                $scope.SKU = codeArray[1].replace("I:", "").trim();
                $scope.ControlNumber = codeArray[0].replace("W:", "").trim(); 
                //$scope.ManufactureDate = codeArray[2].replace("MFG:", "").trim();
                $scope.ManufactureDate = codeArray[2].replace("MFG:", "20").replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3").trim();

                $scope.BatchCode = codeArray[3].replace("B:", "").trim();

                var dataObj = {
                    SessionId: SessionId,
                    JobId: $stateParams.JobId,
                    ManufactureDate: $scope.ManufactureDate, 
                    BatchCode: $scope.BatchCode,
                    SKU: $scope.SKU,
                    ControlNumber: $scope.ControlNumber,
                    CreatedClient: new Date(),
                    Latitude: $scope.lat,
                    Longitude: $scope.long, 
                    Product: { Id : 1}
                };

                $http.post(baseUrl + 'Material/PostNewMaterial', dataObj)
                    .success(function() {
                        alertsManager.addAlert('Success: You have successfully added material.', 'alert-success');
                        $state.go('^');
                    }).error(function(dataObj) {
                        alertsManager.addAlert('Failure Meesage: ' + JSON.stringify({dataObj:dataObj}), 'alert-danger');
                    });
                    $timeout(function(){
                        alertsManager.clearAlerts();
                    }, 5000);

            }, function(error) {
                console.log("An error has happened " + error);
            });
    };
}, false);


}]);
```

})();

The part of the code I am asking for help on is $scope.ManufactureDate

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the code matches one of the formats and if it does, parse it accordingly.

```
if (codeArray[2].match(/MFG:\d+-\d+-\d+/) !== null) {
    /* The format is of 'MFG:000-000-000', \d+ matches 1..n numbers */
    ...
}
```

Or you could combine these to a one regex:

```
let matches = codeArray[2].match(/MFG:(20(\d{2})-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{2}/\d{2}))/);
```

See [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: How would you use that using $scope.ManufacturDate?

Comment: Since according to your question, you *can* handle both formats, easiest is now to make an if clause with a `match(/regex/)`. Then assign the `.ManufacturDate` accordingly.